# How to move fixed div 200px up when reaching the end of the page (when scrolling)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a page with two columns(sidebars).

The left one is fixed (contains google ads) and remains nonchanged even when I scroll down the page.

The right one contains posts and is positioned relative so scrolling is ok.

However I have a footer after right column(sidebar).

This footer's width is 100% of the page.

The problem is that the footer goes to the left sidebar when I scrolled to the bottom.

**I would like to move the left sidebar 200px to the top when I reach 200px from the end of the page when scrolling down.**

And return back when srolling back to the top.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">Google Ads here</div>
    <div id="right">Content posts here</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer here
</div>
```

Comment: Any sample code to work with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No special code, however I have added it to my post.

Comment: take a look on this jquery [plugin](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery scroll . most websites use this to load content for their sites.

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){  

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200){
            setLeftBarPosition();
        }
    });

   function setLeftBarPosition(){
    // your code to set position of lefftbar

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this using plain CSS instead of javascript.

Read [this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position) for details. A Demo [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php)

Comment: that is just a fixed div demo. It does not have any footer or header that spans 100% of the width...

Comment: can you please show your markup ? I am pretty sure that you can solve the issue using fixed positioning.

Comment: Lo Sauer is right I need javascript to know when I am 200px from the bottom.